# My nav will not display as inline block

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm working on a project(using bootstrap) and I can't seem to figure out why my nav is still stacked up instead of being laid out horizontally. I've tried just about everything I can think of and even sought help online where I'm learning to code but they couldn't figure it out either. They told me it should be working and in fact it does work in their code editor, it just doesn't work on my computer which is where the files are located since I don't have web hosting and I'm just learning. I also noticed that in my browser the nav pull-right works and the links are on the right hand side(although they're still not horizontal) but when I ran it through here where it says "run code snippet" the nav appears right underneath the img placeholder, don't know if that means anything but I thought I'd include that bit of information.

```css
header nav ul{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <img id="logo" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
 <nav>
 <ul class="nav pull-right">
  <li><a href="#" class="btn-default">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="btn-default">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="btn-default">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
 </div>
 </div> 
</header>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYezh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to make the navigation to align horizontally?

Then you can try using this

```
header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

working example [here](http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/RapdWE).

The reason your method doesn't work is because you apply to ul instead of the li element.

Comment: Yes, I want to make it align horizontally but that didn't work either.

Comment: Or may be your CSS is being overwritten by other CSS, try adding `!important`, see if it will fix your issue. 
header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block !important;
}

Comment: Right, I had the same issue earlier. I tried it on the editor where I'm learning online and it worked, but it doesn't work on my computer for some reason. I don't have any other CSS files to overwrite it so that's not the issue. Do you think that maybe it has to do with the fact that I'm using the bootstrap framework? I already tried using !important as well, I'm starting to think something is wrong with my computer, I just don't know.

Comment: I tried adding bootstrap into my example and yes, it is from `bootstrap.min.css` that is overwriting the css, take a look how I overwrite the bootstrap css by using the `!important`. http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/EKWMgo

Comment: If you search within the bootstrap CSS, you will find a line that looks like this `.nav>li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}`, This is the CSS responsible for overwriting your CSS

Comment: Wow, it worked dude, thank you very much! I just have no idea why it didn't work the first time I tried it. I did notice that after closing my CSS file on my computer and reopening it earlier today the CSS file had not saved a lot of the changes I made to it, but even taking that into account I applied the necessary changes after I noticed that and it still didn't work, and believe me I double and triple checked my code and even ran it through the W3C validator and it still didn't work until right now.

Comment: I have a suspicion that something is up with my computer because I spent all day stuck on this and the same changes(!important) i made earlier that you suggested didn't work until now. Anyways, thank you very much for your help, it's much appreciated!